# How properly initialize parent and child references between two classes through constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes. First class is `Parent`, which has a list of objects (`Child`). Each of the `Child` has the reference to his `Parent` class. Question is how to implement this reference through the constructor.

```
public sealed class Child
{
    public Child(string id, string name, Parent parent)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Parent ParentInstance { get; private set; }
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class Parent
{
    public Parent(string id, string name, IEnumerable<Child> children)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Children = children;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

The issue is that I have a code which parses some XML code and creates the list of `Parent` objects. Here is the example:

```
internal Parent ParseParent(XElement parentXElement)
{
    return new Parent(parentXElement.Attribute("id").Value, parentXElement.Attribute("name").Value, parentXElement.Descendants("child").Select(ParseChild));
}
```

Of course I can init the `Parent` property within `Parent` constructor, just remove the `private` from `Parent` setter and then go trhough all children and use this property. But I want to make it read-only. Something like this:

```
public Parent(string id, string name, IEnumerable<Child> children)
{
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    Children = children.ForEach(c => c.ParentInstance = this);
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to have the references go both ways? Fundamentally you can't have two instances of immutable types referring to each other cleanly. (You can do stuff within the constructor, passing the as-yet-not-fully-initialized parent to the children for example, but it gets messy.)

Comment: No parent before the child is not born!!

Comment: @JonSkeet I need both ways. What's is the best way to do this? May be you know hot it's implemented in EF code first .Because as i can remember it has a feature where we can declare property for the parent and declare prop for the children.

Comment: I don't know much about EF, but I strongly suspect it's just implemented by the types not being immutable...

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, you was right they are not immutable :) So whats the best way in my case to implement this functionality or may be what should I refactor to make the code look better than with my hack.

Comment: @AntonyBlazer: Implement what functionality, exactly? It's now unclear whether you *do* want mutability or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to parse xml file and create the list of Parent objects each of Parent should contain the list of Child. I need to make these objects immutable. What i want - i want to implement this without any helper classes, for example, like Yaugen Vlasau suggested below.

Comment: Well if you need them to be immutable *and* have cyclic references, that's going to be tricky. You'll probably need to construct the children from the `Parent` constructor, leaking `this` out of the constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be immutable *and* include cyclic references, you'd need something like this:

```
public sealed class Parent
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Child> children;
    private readonly string name; // Just for example

    public Parent(XElement element)
    {
         name = (string) element.Attribute("name");
         children = element.Elements("Child")
                           .Select(x => new Child(x, this))
                           .ToImmutableList(); // Or whatever collection you want
    }
}

public sealed class Child
{
    private readonly Parent parent;
    private readonly string name; // Just for example

    public Child(XElement element, Parent parent)
    {
        this.name = (string) element.Attribute("name");
        // Better not ask the parent for its children yet - they won't be
        // initialized!
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The comment in the `Child` constructor is the bit that should make you raise your eyebrows. Even though `Parent` is immutable, we're leaking `this` before we've finished initializing it... so the `Child` constructor needs to make sure it *doesn't* try to find its siblings during construction.

Comment: This is not the best solution, because my xmlreader has 'parse' methods and these object should be just data object without logic. But thank you for the answer i got you point and will mull over it.

Comment: @AntonyBlazer: If it's not the best solution, that suggests you think there's a better solution to the problem that you've stated (i.e. with requirements of immutability and cyclic references). You've also stated that you don't want callbacks. Do you have any evidence that there *is* a better solution which satisfies your requirements?

Comment: I've thought about your solution, and it's quite good. I've implemented your solution, but extracted code which parse xml to separate class helper. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

one more approach you may try...

```
 class Program
    {

        public sealed class Child
        {
            private readonly Func<Parent> _getParent;

            public Child(string id, string name, Func<Parent> getParent)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                _getParent = getParent;
            }

            public Parent ParentInstance { get { return _getParent(); } }
            public string Id { get; private set; }
            public string Name { get; private set; }
        }

        public sealed class Parent
        {
            public Parent(string id, string name, IEnumerable<Child> children)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                Children = children;
            }

            public string Id { get; private set; }
            public string Name { get; private set; }
            public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; private set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent parent = null;
            Func<Parent> getParent = () => { return parent; };

            parent = new Parent("0", "Parent", new[] {new Child("0", "Child1", getParent), new Child("1", "Child1", getParent)});

            Console.WriteLine(parent.Children.First().ParentInstance.Name);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I also thought about this solution but I want to create objects without callback and any logic, clean Data Objects.

Comment: Now, i've understood this. Thanks for you response

Answer (score 0):

Would it make sence for you if you have a base calss for your Child class that have all except the parent.

```
public sealed class ChildBase
{
    public Child(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

and your child class

```
public sealed class Child : ChildBase
{
    public Child(string id, string name, Parent parent): base(Id, name)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Child(ChildBase stereotype, Parent parent): base(stereotype.Id, stereotype.name)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Parent ParentInstance { get; private set; }
}
```

than your Parent class will whill look like

```
public sealed class Parent
{
    public Parent(string id, string name, IEnumerable<ChildBase> children)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        //Children = children.Select(c => new Child(c.id, c.Name, this));
        Children = children.Select(c => new Child(c, this));
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but I don't like it because of creation new class and making it base. It looks realy complex for  simple feature. And also i see it would be much useful if we don't create childBase and just create RawChildData class without any inheritance and use it in constructor like you did.

Comment: right. inheritance is not a "must to", but it was an approach right of the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your definition of *immutable* is "fields cannot be changed beyond the constructor", what you are asking for is impossible, because in order for the `IEnumerable<Child> children` parameter to exist, it must consist of already-constructed children with null parents. A lazily evaluated sequence of children is also impossible, because defining it would require a reference to the parent that doesn't exist yet.

The only way around this is to make the parent constructor responsible for constructing the children. The opposite (children constructing parents) is impossible, because the parent would already be constructed by the first child, after which its children collection could not be modified -- and if this were a many-to-many relationship, there would simply be no solution.

However if you change your definition to "only parents and children can change each other's fields", you can simply make these generalized `protected` fields in a common base class, or confine the classes to an assembly and make them `internal` fields.